# C# EF6 filter collection on one-to-one foreign key value with dynamic where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, predicate

I have been struggling to build a dynamic where clause that filters a collection of items based on the value of their foreign keys.  I want to filter the base table rows using a where clause against the one-to-one foreign key values.  Here is the base table

```
public class ContactAbbreviation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public int AbbreviationID { get; set; }
    public int RecordStatusID { get; set; }

    public Abbreviation Abbreviation_XRef { get; set; }
}
```

Each ContactAbbreviation has a foreign key of

```
public class Abbreviation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int RecordStatusID { get; set; }
}
```

I have a predicate for each table that allows a dynamic filter to be built based on a search criteria object:

```
public class ContactAbbreviationsFilter
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public int? ContactID { get; set; }
    public int? AbbreviationID { get; set; }
    public int? RecordStatusID { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<ContactAbbreviation, bool>> WhereClause()
    {
        int? ID = this.ID;
        int? ContactID = this.ContactID;
        int? AbbreviationID = this.AbbreviationID;
        int? RecordStatusID = this.RecordStatusID;

        ExpressionStarter<ContactAbbreviation> predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<ContactAbbreviation>(true);

        if (ID != null)
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.ID == ID);

        if (ContactID != null)
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.ContactID == ContactID);

        if (AbbreviationID != null)
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.AbbreviationID == AbbreviationID);

        if (RecordStatusID != null)
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.RecordStatusID == RecordStatusID);

        return predicate;
    }
}

public class AbbreviationFilter
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? RecordStatusID { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<Abbreviation, bool>> WhereClause()
    {
        int? ID = this.ID;
        string Description = this.Description;
        int? RecordStatusID = this.RecordStatusID;

        ExpressionStarter<Abbreviation> predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Abbreviation>(true);

        if (ID != null)
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.ID == ID);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.Description == Description);

        if (RecordStatusID != null)
            predicate = predicate.And(x => x.RecordStatusID == RecordStatusID);

        return predicate;
    }
}
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to filter all ContactAbbreviation rows based on the associated Abbreviation_XRef values using the predicate.  I know that I can hard-code the criteria such as:

```
ContactAbbreviations.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Abbreviation_XRef.RecordStatusID == 1)
```

I could also run an *additional* query against the Abbreviations table to get a list of items that match the search criteria and then attempt an .Any() on the parent where the foreign key column ID is in the list of valid IDs.

What I want to do is filter something like:

```
ContactAbbreviations.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Abbreviation_XRef.<how to apply AbbreviationFilter.WhereClause()>)
```

Since the Abbreviation_XRef isn't an enumerable item, linq can't apply a WHERE statement to it.  Is this even possible?  Here's a quick Fiddle

https://dotnetfiddle.net/EijEaD

Comment: It's going to be something like `.Where(x => predicate(x))`.  To tell you more, I'd need an [mcve].

Comment: The example is included in the linked Fiddle.

Comment: It looks like the fiddle works.  What's the problem?

Comment: What appears to be missing is the passing of your lambda variable into your filter.

Comment: To make it even easier to understand the problem, I forked the original code and made a new Fiddle located here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WrT5aV

You can see that I can't apply the predicate to a single foreign key object because there is no .Where available.

Comment: As you correctly point out, `.Where` operates over `IEnumerable`, whereas your lambda represents an individual item in the collection.  If you need to compare your item with a list, you may be looking for `Contains()`, `Any()` or `All()`.

Comment: But I still think your WhereClause() needs to accept a parameter.  Otherwise, how would it know what to process?  Is that Joseph Albahari's predicate builder?  And are you using Expressions because you want to compose an IQueryable instead of an IEnumerable?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't.  Basically this is what I was trying to accomplish:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/dWqbyh

The predicate can be pre-applied to the column, and then expanded in the .Where clause, thus creating the dynamic where on the secondary table.  The only issue is that it will not work if the predicate is an inherited class.

Comment: I don't see any inheritance in your design (ContactAbbreviationsFilter doesn't inherit from AbbreviationsFilter).  Can you pass a base class as your predicate, inherit from the base class and provide an override method in the inheriting class, relying on runtime polymorphism to pick up the override?

Comment: The fiddle I'm using is a dumbed down version of my production code which is why you don't see the inheritance I'm referring to.  Check out this Fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/c8Gr9k

It gives a general idea of the structure I have.  If you attempt to run that fiddle it will throw an error, but I don't believe that it is actually a timeout issue.  In Visual Studio, the error I am seeing is Unable to create a constant value of type BaseFilter. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.